# ASP.Net MVP - One Business Logic class per Presenter?

Tags: asp.net, mvp

As a general rule of thumb is it acceptable to have two business logic classes utilized in one Presenter in the MVP architecture?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the two logics would do?

Answer (score 1):

Model-View-Presenter is a **user interface** design pattern engineered to facilitate automated unit testing and improve the separation of concerns in **presentation logic**, so there is no problem that you have multiple business logic classes. If you want to separate your business logic to take benefit of separation of concern you should use modularity design pattern.